# Show splash screen each time app becomes active

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen

I want the splash screen to be displayed each time app becomes active. I have created a function `showSplash` which I call in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`

```
-(void)showSplash
{
    UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default.png"]];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: splashScreen];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"begin splash");
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 4.2
                          delay: 0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations: ^{  
                         splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
                         [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                         NSLog(@"end splash");
                     }
     ];
}
```

This is how I call this function :

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
[self showSplash];
}
```

But no splash screen appears. Please correct me.

Comment: Do you see your log messages being printed?

Comment: @PhillipMills : Yes. They get printed but the splash is never displayed.

Comment: @Nitish Maybe you would like to use a launch xib or storyboard. Take a look at http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/12/24/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard.html

Comment: @devgr : How does that help to display the splash screen whenever app becomes active ?

Comment: What type is `self.window.rootViewController`? Also `makeKeyAndVisible` is only going to bring it forward if the window is on the current view controller. If you want the rootViewController's main window, you'd want `[self.window.rootViewController.view.window makeKeyAndVisible]`.

Comment: I tried your code it works well, have you check if your "Default.png" issue?

Comment: Use GCD to invoke `showSplash` after a brief interval.

Comment: @Nitish : Look at the answer, I gave just now. You have to do it in a two step process. When the app is resigning the active state. This way, iOS will take snapshot of that splashscreen which will help you when the app has actually become ACTIVE. Once app is active, you can show the same splash screen for some duration.

Comment: If you really want/need to display a splash screen at launch, cool. But just so you are aware, Apple is strongly against this. From the *iOS HIG* (ch. iOS Design Basics, sect. Starting & Stopping), emphasis theirs: "__As much as possible, avoid displaying a splash screen or other startup experience.__ It’s best when users can begin using your app immediately."

Comment: @BlakeMerryman : I am fully aware of this. Thanks though. It's a product I am working on and not an AppStore app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after adding the splash view - bring it to front

change

```
UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default.png"]];
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: splashScreen];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

to

```
UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default.png"]];
[self.window addSubview: splashScreen];
[self.window bringSubviewToFront: splashScreen]; //!
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want the application to have a fresh start every time you get back to it, you could also disable background execution, as stated in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1) (last section titled "Opting Out of Background Execution"):

> If you do not want your app to run in the background at all, you can
>   explicitly opt out of background by adding the
>   **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** key (with the value YES) to your app’s
>   **Info.plist** file.

Comment: That is a good point. Thanks. But I only want the splash to appear every time. Rest of app comes as it was when it was left in background.

Answer (score 2):

Please, ensure your window root view controller main view is the top most view in your App in the moment you want to show splash...

Answer (score 2):

Check frame of splashScreen (UIImageView). Set its frame to bounds of your root view controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to *hunt* the top view controller with a recursion like this:

```
- (UIViewController *)findTopViewController {
   return [self topViewControllerFrom:self.window.rootViewController];
}

- (UIViewController *)topViewControllerFrom:(UIViewController *)vc {
    if (vc.navigationController.visibleViewController != nil) {
        return [self topViewControllerFrom:vc.navigationController.visibleViewController];
    }
    if (vc.tabBarController.selectedViewController != nil) {
        return [self topViewControllerFrom:vc.tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    }
    return vc;
}
```

Now calling `[self findTopViewController]` should hopefully return the currently visible/top VC of your app, and you can do:

```
[[self findTopViewController].view addSubview:splashScreen];
...
```

Comment: Thank but it's not showing. This is the change I made as per you :  UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default.png"]];
    [[self findTopViewController].view addSubview:splashScreen];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: Try to put a breakpoint on `applicationDidBecomeActive`, then when it breaks run this in the console: `po [self findTopViewController]`, do you get a view controller or `nil`?

Comment: Yes this returned nil. But even when I get my rootViewController which I have in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions - UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProjectsController"];
        rootController = rootViewController; it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you calling something like `self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController` after calling `[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier...`?

Comment: @Nitish Did you try setting frame of splash screen image view like splashScreen.frame=rootViewController.bounds?

Comment: @AvielGross : Doing this : UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProjectsController"];
        rootController = rootViewController;

Comment: I don't fully understand what is `rootController` but if you are doing `UIViewController *rootViewController =.....` then after that also call `self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController`

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#define kSplashScreen (UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height == 568) ? @"Default-568h" \
            : (UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height == 667) ? @"Default-667" \
            : (UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height == 736) ? @"Default-Portrait" \
            : @"Default"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic) UIWindow *splashWindow;
@property (nonatomic) UIWindow *keyWindow;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSplashConfigured) BOOL splashConfigured;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isShowingSplash) BOOL showingSplash;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self animateSplash];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self showOrHideSplash];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self showOrHideSplash];
}

- (void)showOrHideSplash
{
    [self.splashWindow setHidden:[self isShowingSplash]];
    if ([self isShowingSplash])
    {
        [self.keyWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.splashWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self animateSplash];
    }
    self.showingSplash = !self.showingSplash;
}


- (void)animateSplash
{
    if ([self isSplashConfigured])
    {
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:self.splashWindow];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else
    {
        self.keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        self.splashWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        self.splashWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        self.splashWindow.rootViewController.view.frame = self.splashWindow.bounds;
        UIImageView *splashImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kSplashScreen]];
        splashImage.frame = self.splashWindow.bounds;
        [self.splashWindow.rootViewController.view addSubview:splashImage];
        [self.splashWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        [self.splashWindow setHidden:YES];
        self.splashConfigured = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"begin splash");
    __weak AppDelegate* weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.2 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations: ^{
        weakSelf.splashWindow.alpha = 1.0;
        weakSelf.splashWindow.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
        [weakSelf.splashWindow removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"end splash");
    }];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit cumbersome solution, but it works fine. The idea is add new `UIWindow` on top of all controllers

```
- (void)showSplash {
    id <UIApplicationDelegate> appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[appDelegate window].frame];
    UIViewController *splashController = [UIViewController new];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    splashController.view = imgView;
    window.rootViewController = splashController;
    window.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
    window.hidden = NO;
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.2 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        window.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        window.hidden = YES;
        window.rootViewController = nil;
        [[appDelegate window] makeKeyAndVisible];
        [[appDelegate window] setNeedsDisplay];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please find below a solution for this problem.

Split the splash screen code into two methods; `showSplash` and `hideSplash`.

Call `showSplash` in the method `applicationWillResignActive`. In the method, create and add the `imageView` to `rootViewController`; set it's alpha to 0.0f and then animate it to alpha 1.0f. This is to make sure that the user doesn't see the imageView when the app is going to background.

Now call `hideSplash` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. In `hideSplash` remove the imageView with animation. See the code below;

```
-(void)showSplash
{
    _splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default"]];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:_splashScreen];
    _splashScreen.alpha = 0.0f;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        _splashScreen.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
}
- (void)hideSplash
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 4.2
                          delay: 0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations: ^{
                         _splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
                         [_splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                         NSLog(@"end splash");
                     }
     ];
}
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self showSplash];
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self hideSplash];
}
```

I hope this helps! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
splashScreen.frame = self.window.rootViewController.view.frame;
```

below

```
UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"alertBg.png"]];
```

example

```
-(void)showSplash
{
    UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"Default.png"]];
    splashScreen.frame = self.window.rootViewController.view.frame;
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: splashScreen];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    NSLog(@"begin splash");
    [UIView animateWithDuration: 4.2
                          delay: 0.5
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations: ^{
                         splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;
                     }
                     completion: ^ (BOOL finished) {
                         [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                         NSLog(@"end splash");
                     }
     ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to achieve this is to add the image in `AppDelegate's window`.
In the below code `statusView` is one of the view, which consist of some image. So add it to your `AppDelegate's window` as a `subView`

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] addSubview:statusView];
```

Now whenever you want it to appear for some amount of time, you show this view, but same time **bring it to front**.

```
-(void)showStatusView{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] bringSubviewToFront:statusView];
        statusView.alpha = 1;
    }];
}
```

Better Call the above method on the `AppDelegate's` method  `didBecomeActive`.

*Also, show the splash screen as soon as application is going to resign active*. This way, iOS will take the snapshot of the screen, which will be shown for fraction of seconds when the app is about to become active.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self showStatusView];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self showStatusView];
}
```

Once the app is active, you can show the actual splash screen for some duration & then your usual app state.

Answer (score 2):

First create your launch screen or image in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

[image: AppDelegate.m]

After this write your code like this-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Root view controller is not always the presented view controller. This can cause your splash screen to be hidden under bunch of other view controllers. Try using something like (swift syntex):

```
func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController?{
    if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController{
        while ((topController.presentedViewController) != nil) {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController!
        }
        return topController
    }
    return nil
}
```

And add your splash view to the top view controller

Answer (score 1):

launch your application normally every-time, call your method in applicationBecomeActive, and add you image view on Appdelegate.window and remove it after some time by timer.

```
[self.window addSubview: splashScreen];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following line:

```
[self.window addSubview: splashScreen];
```

instead of

```
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview: splashScreen];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse your `launchScreen` to show up instead of showing imageview. This comes handdy when you have complex launchscreen instead of single image as a splash screen.

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last,
              let launchScreen = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController(),
              let launchView = launchScreen.view else {return}
        launchView.tag = 8888
        launchView.frame = window.bounds
        launchView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        window.addSubview(launchView)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.last,
              let view = window.viewWithTag(8888) else {return}
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```